# setRequestInterception support for Firefox in Puppeteer

Tags: firefox, puppeteer

Does `setRequestInterception` work for Firefox on Puppeteer?

In my tests, whenever launching with Firefox, I do get:

```
Protocol error (Fetch.enable): Fetch.enable RemoteAgentError@chrome://remote/content/Error.jsm:25:5
```

on `await page.setRequestInterception(true);`

I know that currently Firefox is in experimental mode for Puppeteer. So I expect this feature may not be supported.
Is there any other way that I could handle requests (like alter requests, mock responses) when running on Firefox?

This is how I launch the browser (I can see Firefox window, and all other tests pass):

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  product: "firefox", 
  headless: false,
  slowMo: 50,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Puppeteer for Firefox does not support `setRequestInterception` yet.
You can keep a track of passing tests at https://puppeteer.github.io/ispuppeteerfirefoxready/

Here is how we launch firefox:

During installation, choose Puppeteer version ^3.0.0

```
PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm install
```

Options:

```
puppeteerOptions: {
        args: args,
        //ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation'],
        headless: false,
        //slowMo: 17,
        //executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
        executablePath: './node_modules/puppeteer/.local-firefox/mac-79.0a1/Firefox Nightly.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox'
    },
```